# Is it possible to access the API programatically?

Tags: nest-api

I've been looking at the API docs all evening, and as far as I can tell, there is no way to work with the API 100% programatically. Even this doc, https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/sample-code-auth, which includes the header "Send the authorization post call programmatically", describes a process by where I have to get and run my authorization code in a browser.

So is there *anyway* to avoid all? My intent is to build a Node library to access API calls with a user's credentials.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to skip OAuth. You can utilize redirect URI's to skip the PIN code method. You send the user to the Nest login page with your client id, the user logs in, and the token is sent to a pre-determined location in your app or server.

Users raw credentials shouldn't be used. Auth tokens should be used for all interactions with the Nest API.

Comment: You say "shouldn't", but is it possible? Basically I want to set up a Node service to get my camera's still picture at an interval. Is something like that impossible?

Comment: There is an unofficial API but using it is a security risk and unsupported. I really recommend staying away from it. If you're building this for yourself I would just get a token using cURL or postman, they are good for 10 years. If you're looking to build something for others then OAuth is a requirement. Node actually has a lot of OAuth 2 libraries that make authentication pretty easy.

Comment: I know OAuth is easy in Node, that's not the issue - it's having an automated system. If the tokens persist for a very long time, it may still be worthwhile to build the demo.

Comment: Yeah there are no refresh tokens. They are issues for 10 years or until revoked.